# How do I ensure that my website is accessible to the disabled?

Tags: accessibility, web

How can I ensure (or try to make) web access available for all - who may have a variety of disabiltes?

Any advice for any standards or web sites that could give me some pragmatic advice for the design of a site?

Comment: Your question is very broad in scope and not answerable in its current format - any specific disabilities you have in mind? Please reduce the scope of the question.

Comment: Oded - No particular disability in mind - Would like it to the broadest audience. This is espesically true for web sites for charies and government agencies.

Comment: To all who have answered this question - thank you. I have read the documents that have been noted and intend to the best of my abilities to implement them. There is a large, untapped market or there that is becomming disenfranshised. That includes the elderly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a number of considerations you need to address here, if your website isn't catering for a specific disability then you have to work on a broad range of features. In this situation the first thing you need to remember is that you sadly can't cater to everyone. Look at the list below and identify which of these disabilities you can sensibly cater for

> **Visual**: Visual impairments including blindness, various common types
> of low vision and poor eyesight, various types of color blindness;
>
> **Motor/Mobility**: e.g. difficulty or inability to use the hands,
> including tremors, muscle slowness, loss of fine muscle control, etc.,
> due to conditions such as Parkinson's Disease, muscular dystrophy,
> cerebral palsy, stroke;
>
> **Auditory**: Deafness or hearing impairments,
> including individuals who are hard of hearing;
>
> **Seizures**: Photoepileptic seizures caused by visual strobe or flashing effects.
>
> **Cognitive/Intellectual**: Developmental disabilities, learning
> disabilities (dyslexia, dyscalculia, etc.), and cognitive disabilities
> of various origins, affecting memory, attention, developmental
> "maturity," problem-solving and logic skills, etc.

The easiest here is the **Seizures**, eliminate flashing / strobing content from your site, or more importantly if you cant put up a warning before displaying this type of content.

Users with **Motor / Mobility** issues may have problems interacting with content on your site that requires a high amount of precision, this can be helped by increasing the size of your UI elements, or allowing the user to resize these elements if needed.

Generally make anything clickable as large as is feasible and if you have elements that have features such as drag drop, make the drag handles large so the user doesn't have to click a tiny area.

**Auditory** is also a fairly easy consideration to make, at the least simply provide text alternatives to any media content your site may have, for larger sites using video then considerations such as sign language may be an option.

**Visual** is probably the most common consideration web developers need to make. Firstly partially sighted users may want to increase the text size to your page, so make sure that your UI can cope with this. Use clear and readable fonts and make sure there is contrast between the background color and the font color.

**Color blind** users may wish to change your site color scheme to meet their needs, you can find information easily on the types of color blindness and develop a couple of alternative CSS styles to meet these needs. Also a high contrast option for everything on your site may benefit partially sighted users.

**Cognitive / Intellectual** is one of the harder considerations to meet, so look at the individual disabilities. ADD for instance makes it hard for a person to focus and makes them easily distracted, considering this think about advertisements, they are designed to distract us and draw our attention, thus by limiting advertisements on your site you can get rid of the ones that flash and scream Click ME!.

**Dyslexic** users may struggle with reading huge chunks of text which also fits in with considerations for partially sighted people, here you could have an audio option so the text is read aloud to the user.

One more consideration here is the use of color in your website. It has been proven that certain colors can stimulate emotions, for someone with emotional or developmental issues using colors that are considered calming vs ones that excite (reds for example) may improve their experience of your website.

All of the above are design considerations, looking at the development (Code) next there isn't too much you can do, most of the considerations about your code are because of third party applications interacting with your site.

Generally make sure your code is well formed, correct tags / closing tags etc. Make sure it is valid HTML / XHTML / CSS etc if you can validate to the strict standards it wont hurt your cause. Tags such as links / images should have appropriate Alt text to describe what the element is, for instance alt="image1" is fairly useless to a screen reader but alt="Image showing ...... clicking this will take you to....." is useful.

If you can find some trial software grab yourself a screen reader, load up your website, close your eyes and try interact with it, its going to be hard but at least you can see how your user will interact with your site and more importantly you can use the screen reader to check your site actually gets read the way it should.

There are plenty of 3rd party plugins you can integrate with your site to aid your users too, so look into those, things like the option to magnify text or read aloud with just a click will be well received as long as they are not too intrusive to your non disabled users.

Helpful links

http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG10/ The W3C Disability guidelines are a good place to start
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_accessibility Wikipedia web accessability
http://www.etre.com/tools/colourblindsimulator/ Allows you to see how images will appear to colourblind users
http://colorfilter.wickline.org/
http://www.w3.org/WAI/ W3C Web Accessability Initiative Guidelines

Comment: These links might fit in the list. A shorter accessibility checklist: [WCAG2 at a Glance](http://www.w3.org/2009/cheatsheet/#wcag2), and two screenReader emulators that help you spot problems for screenreaders: [ChromeShades](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/hlklboladblmgfpkenhlgbhoojdlfoao), which works well for dynamic webpages because the website are shown in-place and directly updates after changes, [Fangs](http://www.standards-schmandards.com/projects/fangs/) a firefox plugin which is recommended in the chrome shades documentation, for static websites and simple dynamic content.

Answer (score 5):

Section 508 is the section of the law that requires that US government websites be accessible.

More information is here, including best practices on making content accessible to all.

http://www.section508.gov/

Generally you should support screen readers by using semantic markup, and avoid flashy content and audio -- these are usually impossible or just difficult to make accessible.

You should also look at web typography guidelines and look to hiring a good designer. Poor color schemes, typefaces, and font sizes make reading on the web much harder than it needs to be.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am not American but any ideas is much apppreciated. I just think that not enough is done to aid in disabled customers. Largely they are an untapped market.

Answer (score 5):

If you're from the UK, from a legal POV you want to be looking at the [Equality Act](http://www.rnib.org.uk/professionals/webaccessibility/lawsandstandards/Pages/uk_law.aspx) (which replaced the Disability Discrimination Act).

The foundation of web accessibility is based on the graceful degradation/progessive enhancement model (sounds more complicated than it is!). [A List Apart wrote a great article on it some time ago.](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/understandingprogressiveenhancement/)

A good starting point for web professionals is the [RNIB's Web Access Centre](http://www.rnib.org.uk/professionals/webaccessibility/Pages/web_accessibility.aspx). Obviously this mainly deals with those user who experience visual disability, but it's a very useful resource.

[Web AIM](http://webaim.org/) is also a good site for resources/articles although I'm not sure how often it's maintained these days (still, the information there is relevant).

There are far too many individual little things to bear in mind when developing accessible interfaces, but if you take the time to read some of the articles on those sites, you'll pick up the fundamentals which will then lead you onto the more nitty-gritty things.

Accessible development is about a change in mindset as much as learning the nuts and bolts. You need to to be constantly asking yourself "How might other people use this? What barriers might be in their way? What browser are they using? Does this work without colour/JavaScript/CSS?". Learn how to take your site apart and see if it still works.

Answer (score 3):

Web Content Accessibility Guidelines 2.0 (**WCAG 2.0**) is the W3C Recommendation from Web Accessibility Initiative (W3C/WAI).

An overview can be found here: http://www.w3.org/WAI/intro/wcag20
There are very broad Principles as well as precise Techniques (for HTML, CSS, JS, Flash, etc) and the intent of each and every criteria. These aren't documents meant to be read at once and you'll want to learn more from tutorials and articles found on the web (archives at [456 Berea Street](http://www.456bereastreet.com/), WebAIM, [videos about accessibility](http://webaxe.blogspot.com/2011/08/accessibility-videos.html))

Answer (score 2):

The [W3C Quick Reference guide to WCAG 2](http://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG20/quickref/) lists all of the relevant techniques you'll need to implement the WCAG2 principles and guidelines that Felipe mentioned, with code examples if appropriate on the individual technique pages. If it's all a bit too technical for you, [WebAIM's checklist](http://webaim.org/standards/wcag/checklist) is the same thing only in plain English.

Unfortunately there's no magic wand for getting sites to be compliant. You have to go through each bit of content and test it and modify it if necessary. Luckily, even some small improvements can make a big difference.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of good answers, but I can't help adding my input as well.

If you want to ensure a website is disabled friendly, there are a number of considerations that should be taken. One that I have not seen on here (perhaps because I skimmed) is to ensure that you use high-contrast colors, with a solid background behind text.

However, you should NOT use white on black or white on black...dyslexics commonly cannot see those colors. Use an off-white for background or text.

Also, make sure your text is large. Ensure as much of the content as possible is standard text, so that text-to-speech programs can "read" the website. Text-to-speech cannot read images. Text links instead of buttons would also be advisable, for the same reasons (though there may be a means of associating text with a button for these scenarios...?)